# I have a question about using GoogleMap in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use GoogleMap in Flutter.

But I faced some errors like below.

From looking for the error below for a while, it is said to be an error caused by incorrectly referencing the memory.

Is there a solution?

```
F/libc    (24240): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 24290 (RenderThread), pid 24240 (omyourroom.mryr)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.190920.001/5891938:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2021-03-11 01:12:34+0000
pid: 24240, tid: 24290, name: RenderThread  >>> com.myroomyourroom.mryr <<<
uid: 10166
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    eax 90d0a000  ebx cc5bd864  ecx cc4275c0  edx 0000b1b4
    edi a5068a00  esi bbb6e840
    ebp d832c354  esp bf52747c  eip 00000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
      #01 pc 0286b00a  /system/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x66c000) (BuildId: ffe50d4377c82928759c1f40f1b35ba9f411454a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never find an error like that before, it's unclear the step to reproduce. How it happens, when it happens, why it happens? I think there is something wrong with your ADB / emulator or the map plugin itself.

and also if you don't mind please check this plugin. I work with that too for my apps, they working flawlessly
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_maps

You can see on the main page an example of how to implement it correctly